# Perron-Frobenius Theorem and probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

Consider the following probability problem:

Assume that if it rains some day, then  the probability to rain the following day is $0.75$. Now if it doesn't rain some day, then  the probability to rain the following day is $0.1$.

If we note $p_n$ the probability to rain in the $n$-th day and $q_n=1-p_n$, then we would have
$$p_{n+1}=0.75p_n+0.1q_n$$
$$q_{n+1}=0.25p_n+0.9q_n$$
Thus we will get the following geometric recurrence relation $$U_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    p_{n+1}  \\
    q_{n+1}
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0.75 & 0.1\\
    0.25 & 0.9
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    p_{n}  \\
    q_{n}
    \end{pmatrix}=QU_n$$
How can we prove that in general if the transition matrix $Q$ contains only positive entries, then the sequence of probability state $(U_n)_n$ will converge to the steady states $U$ which solves the equation: $$U=QU.$$ In this case $$U=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{2}{7}  \\
    \frac{5}{7}
    \end{pmatrix}.$$

I heard that this has to do with the Perron-Frobenius Theorem.

**Note**: I know that we can solve this problem simply by solving the recurrence relation $$p_{n+1}=0.75p_n+0.1q_n=0.65p_n+0.1.$$ But I am just interested in the matricial aspect of the problem.

Comment: If you want to read about Frobenius theorem I would recommend reading Lawler's book on stochastic processes. Also, I guess you can diagonalize that matrix to find its limit

Comment: @MarkoffChainz Thanks a lot I will check this book.